# How to select first master record on page load in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

in Oracle apex sample master detail application, when we run side by side page it shows like below. now i need to select first master record by default on page load, so that user should not click every time when the new page loads.

[image: Sample Master Detail Application - Side by Side Page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Master-Detail, side by side there is a page item for the selected master record. You can use a computation or page process to set that value.
Example for the emp/dept sample schema:

1. Create Master Detail, Side by Side page with master table dept and child table emp
2. This will create (among other regions) a region for 'Dept' for the master record with a page item `P1_DEPTNO`. You'll notice that that master region is of type "Classic Report" on table `DEPT` with a where clause or `"DEPTNO" = :P1_DEPTNO`. That is the clue - set a value for P1_DEPTNO on page load.
3. Create a before header computation on `P1_DEPTNO` of type "SQL Query (return single value)" with source

```
SELECT deptno FROM dept ORDER BY dname FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS only
```

Run the page and observe the first record is checked. Change the query of the computation source to meet any requirements you have.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i implemented this solution in application but faced a new type of challenge. actually my application is based on a view which contain non-approved transactions. now the requirement is, once the transaction is approved by clicking the approve button, current record will be gone from the page and next master record should be selected. unfortunately i am unable to assign the next transaction_id in parameter variable.